# Conditional Entry When Creating Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have done this and it works.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
 Employee_ID varchar2(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 Office_ID varchar2(7) NOT NULL,
 Emp_FirstName varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
 Emp_LastName varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
 Emp_Gender varchar2(1) NOT NULL, 
 Emp_DateOfBirth Date NOT NULL,
 Hire_Date date NOT NULL,
 Emp_CurrentDate date default sysdate,
 Emp_Telephone varchar2(11) NOT NULL,
 Emp_Email varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
 Emp_AddressLine varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
 Emp_PostCode varchar2(8) NOT NULL,
 Emp_Speciality varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
 Emp_Qualification varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
 Emp_AwardingBody varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
 Emp_Salary number(6) NOT NULL,
 Emp_Supervised_By varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
 Employment_History1 varchar2(50),
 Employment_History2 varchar2(50),
 Employment_History3 varchar2(50) ,
 CONSTRAINT fk_staff_office FOREIGN KEY (Office_ID) REFERENCES office (Office_ID), 
 CONSTRAINT Hire_Date_CK check (Hire_Date < Emp_CurrentDate AND (Hire_Date - Emp_DateOfBirth)/365 > 18),
 CONSTRAINT Emp_DateOfBirth_CK check (Emp_DateOfBirth > TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
 CONSTRAINT Emp_Salary_CK check (Emp_Salary > 0 AND Emp_Salary < 150000),
 CONSTRAINT Emp_Gender_CK CHECK (Emp_Gender in ('M','F')), 
 CONSTRAINT Emp_Email_CK CHECK ( Emp_Email like '%_@__%._%'),
 CONSTRAINT Emp_Telephone_CK CHECK (regexp_like(Emp_Telephone, '^[0123456789]{11}$') AND Emp_Telephone like '0%'),
 CONSTRAINT Emp_FirstName_CK CHECK (regexp_like(Emp_FirstName, '^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]{1,20}$')),
 CONSTRAINT Emp_LastName_CK CHECK (regexp_like(Emp_LastName, '^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]{1,20}$')),
 CONSTRAINT Emp_PostCode_CK CHECK (regexp_like ( Emp_PostCode , '([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z]))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})')),
 CONSTRAINT Emp_Speciality_CK CHECK (regexp_like(Emp_Speciality, '^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ]{1,20}$')),
 CONSTRAINT Emp_Qualification_CK CHECK (regexp_like(Emp_Qualification, '^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ]{1,20}$')),
 CONSTRAINT Emp_AwardingBody_CK CHECK (regexp_like(Emp_AwardingBody, '^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ]{1,30}$'))
 );
```

What I want to do now is to create a constraint that enables me to set the value of the attribute `Emp_Supervised_By` automatically as the same value of the `Employee_ID` attribute when the `Emp_Speciality` is 'Manager'.

I tried to do it like this but it doesn't work:

`CONSTRAINT Emp_Supervised_By_CK check (CASE WHEN Emp_Speciality = 'MANAGER' THEN Emp_Supervised_By = Employee_ID)`

**Is a requirement to use CONSTRAINTS NOT TRIGGERS**.

Comment: A constraint does not set a value of a column automatically.  You are misunderstanding something.

Comment: No such thing as varchar2, number, etc. in sql server. You must be using a different dbms - which doesn't change the answer but it is worth highlighting.

Comment: I meant SQL DEVELOPER ! SORRY !

Comment: How can I do this then ? Because I want it to be automatically stored like a total for example. I think this is called "Computed Column"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you mentioned computed columns, maybe your business requirement can be satisfied with the below instead of a constraint.

```
    CREATE TABLE Employee (
     ...
     Employee_ID varchar2(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     Emp_Speciality varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
     Emp_Supervised_By AS (CASE WHEN Emp_Speciality = 'Manager' THEN Employee_ID ELSE NULL END)
     ....
     );
```

Comment: It WORKS! Thank You so much! You are a true life saver!

Comment: Can you please tell me if there is a way to calculate the total applying the same rule as before, when i want to calculate a total using the attributes from another entity?

Comment: @Cosmin That's a different question, so you are best off asking it seperately. Before doing that I would suggest checking out if you can create a function and then call it in the computed column definition.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it works:

`CREATE TABLE OrderLine (
    Invoice_ID varchar2(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Item_ID varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
    Unit_Price number(6,2) NOT NULL,
    Quantity number(6) NOT NULL,
    Total_Price number(38,2) AS (CASE WHEN Quantity >= 50 THEN 
    ((Unit_Price*Quantity)-((Unit_Price*Quantity)*0.80)) ELSE Unit_Price*Quantity END) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_item_invoice FOREIGN KEY(Invoice_ID) REFERENCES Invoice (Invoice_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_item_item FOREIGN KEY(Item_ID) REFERENCES Item (Item_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Unit_Price_CK CHECK (Unit_Price > 0),
    CONSTRAINT Quantity_CK CHECK (Quantity > 0),
    CONSTRAINT Total_Price_CK CHECK (Total_Price > 0)
);`

`CREATE TABLE Invoice (
     Invoice_ID varchar2(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     Office_ID varchar2(7) NOT NULL,
     Invoice_Date Date NOT NULL,
     Total_Cost number (9) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT fk_order_Office FOREIGN KEY(Office_ID) REFERENCES Office (Office_ID),
     CONSTRAINT Total_Cost_CK CHECK (Total_Cost > 0)
);`

I want to calculate The TotalCost like the sum of TotalPrice(s).

Is there a way to use the same approach ass before ?